# Fix If/Else Loop with UpdateCursor when attribute value is Null

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, null

I have a python script that I use to make batch updates on a database in GIS.

I'm using Update Cursors to update the values of an attribute table, which has worked flawlessly when I am updating records for the first time since UpdateCurosrs overwrite the data (from what I understand as a still-newish coder).

When I revisit a record and need to add (or append) comments to a populated record, I can do so in two different chunks of code, but its clunky and requires additional steps. I'm trying to combine these two pieces of code into a single script with a nested if/else loop.

To overwrite blank attributes, this code works perfectly

```py
fc=DB
fieldname=["StationID","StationStatus","StatusComments_Source"]

for i in confirm: 
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc,fieldname) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            if (row[0]== i):
                row[1]= "Confirm" #Data Confirmed
                row[2]= StatusComments_Source #Comments    
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

If I want to append comments to existing fields, this code works perfectly. This code will break if that attribute field for row2 is empty.

```py
for i in confirm: 
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc,fieldname) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            if (row[0]== i):
                row[1]= "Confirm" #Data Confirmed
                confcom=[]
                confcom.append(StatusComments_Source)
                row[2]=''.join(confcom)
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

This is the loop I tried to create, "If row2 is null, overwrite the data, else: append the comments

```py
for i in confirm: 
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc,fieldname) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            if (row[0]== i):
                row[1]= "Confirm" #Data Confirmed
                if row[2] is None:
                    row[2] = StatusComments_Source
                else:
                    confcom=[]
                    confcom.append(row[2],", ")
                    confcom.append(StatusComments_Source)
                    row[2]=''.join(confcom)
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

But I get this error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\CEI2\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_19768\350652596.py", line 13, in <cell line: 4>
    confcom.append(row[2],", ")

TypeError: list.append() takes exactly one argument (2 given)
```

I'd appreciate any help with this!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an existing comma-separated field, and you want to add another item to it, use `split()` to separate it into a list, append to that list, join it back to a string and assign that back to the field.

```
if row[2] is None:
    row[2] = StatusComments_Source
else:
    confcom=row[2].split(', ')
    confcom.append(StatusComments_Source)
    row[2]=', '.join(confcom)
```

You can also just use string concatenation:

```
row[2] += f', {StatusComments_Source}'
```

Comment: Barmar, this worked perfectly, thank you very much!
I'm confused by the second option you provided. Is that supposed to replace the lines after the else: statement? Is the f' variable referencing something, or is that part of the script?

Comment: Yes, it replaces everything after `else:`. `f` is not a variable, it's an [f-string](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/).